# dimension of the quotient of a bialgebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am stuck in a proof of a lemma that I am in need of. The situation is as follows: Let $k$ be a field and $A$ and $B$ two finite-dimensional $k$-bialgebras, where the dimension of $A$ is a prime number $p$ and $B \neq k$. Suppose further that you have a surjective homomorphism of $k$-bialgebras $A \to B$. Then the dimension of $B$ should also be equal to $p$.

I have been trying to understand this particular step for quite some time and have come to think that I am missing some general knowledge about bialgebras here. It would of course be sufficient to show, that the dimension of $B$ must divide the Dimension of $A$, but this does not follow from pure linear algebra, so there must be more to it.

This is taken from the proof of Lemma 1 in the article "Group Schemes of Prime Order", which can be found here

http://homepages.uni-regensburg.de/~nan25776/tate_oort_group_schemes_of_prime_order.pdf

If someone could help me out, I would be much obliged.

Comment: Are you sure you want $k$-bialgebras, not $k$-Hopf algebras? If so, you can consider the $5$-element monoid $\left<x \mid x^4 = x^5 \right>$ and its $4$-element quotient $\left<x \mid x^3 = x^4 \right>$; taking the free $k$-vector spaces on them gives you a surjective $k$-bialgebra homomorphism from a $5$-dimensional $k$-bialgebra to a $4$-dimensional bialgebra.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have $k$-Hopf algebras, you can show that if $f : A \to B$ is a surjective homomorphism of finite-dimensional $k$-Hopf algebras, then $\dim B \mid \dim A$. Indeed, it is enough to prove the dual statement, viz., that if $f : B \to A$ is an injective homomorphism of finite-dimensional $k$-Hopf algebras, then $\dim B \mid \dim A$. This follows from the Nichols-Zoeller theorem (or its generalization the Skryabin theorem): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83854/lagranges-theorem-for-hopf-algebras . There might be a simpler proof in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not true if you only have bialgebras. Take for example $M$ the multiplicative monoid of $\mathbb Z_3$ and $k$ a field; write the elements of $M$ $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=0$. Then $c$ generates an biideal.